# How to turn on all default binding keys of vi-editing-mode on bash?

Tags: bash, readline

I am using vi-editing-mode on Bash. According to `man readline`, there are a couple of default binding keys working on vi-editing-mode. Some keys work well, but some other default keys do not work.

For example, `man readline` says,

```
VI Command Mode functions
...
         "C-E"  emacs-editing-mode
...
```

But `bind -p` on my linux box says that 'emacs-editing-mode` is not bound on any key.

```
$ bind -p | grep emacs-editing
# emacs-editing-mode (not bound)
```

Is this a normal situation? How to turn on all default binding keys of vi-editing-mode on bash? Do I have to bind keys manually on .inputrc?

Answer (score 1):

Bash modifies a few default readline bindings including this one. The code is in the [`initialize_readline` function in `bashline.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/bashline.c?id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961#n406).

> ```
> /* In Bash, the user can switch editing modes with "set -o [vi emacs]",
>    so it is not necessary to allow C-M-j for context switching.  Turn
>    off this occasionally confusing behaviour. */
> ```

The mode-switching keys are the only ones that are unbound. Some additional keys are bound (e.g. for bash-specific completion like `M-$` to complete variable names).